# Can't add DialogAPI to outlook addin manifest

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I wan't to use `displayDialogAsync` in my outlook addin, but when i add `DialogAPI` to manifest:

```
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.4"/>
      <Set Name="DialogAPI"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

I get following error: `This app can't be installed. The Requirements element can only include one Set element. The name of the Set element must be 'Mailbox'..`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `displayDialogAsync` API is in both Mailbox 1.4 and DialogApi, so you don't need anything more that Mailbox 1.4. For more information, see [displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=common-js#displaydialogasync-startaddress--options--callback-). Scroll down to **Remarks** | **Requirement sets**.